# Why does gnome-terminal $TERM display xterm

Tags: 13.10, gnome-terminal, colors, xterm

I'm trying to get the solarized color scheme in my terminal and am working through some tutorials online. I have run across the $TERM environment variable that from my understanding is the current name of the terminal I'm using. I also have a $COLORTERM which I'm not quite sure what it is but it shows me: `gnome-terminal` whereas the $TERM variable is `xterm`. Isn't the terminal that Ubuntu 13.10 uses the gnome-terminal? Why is xterm being displayed in the env var?

Comment: Side-effect of update-alternatives.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It has the same reason why almost every webbrowser (FF,IE,Safari,Chrome,...) uses *Mozilla* in their User Agent String.

The `TERM` variable set to `xterm` only means that your terminal is compatible with the `xterm` terminal (has the same capabilities), so the system can treat it and communicate with it as it would with an `xterm`. The system has the `terminfo` database which stores the terminal capabilities for various terminals (`/lib/terminfo` directory), and in that terminfo database there is no such as `gnome-terminal`.

For some more info look at [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/23779/53591) or look up the manpages of `terminfo` or `infocmp`